# Working in heat

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

What does working in temperatures of 180 degree dry heat for long periods do to the body?

Such as inside of a cooking cyclone scraping product out of it while it's still at 180 degrees.

Comment: 180°C or 180°F ?

Comment: 180°F while in use it gets to 250°F